# Enable static checks for constant evaluation

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, static-assert

I like to have some sort of static (compile-time) check, if a type is initialised with a constant.

Below is a test code.
The type C is just a test to see if/when constant-evaluation is triggered.

The type D is more to be a real example of what I want to do:

1. Runtime: if D is initialized with the wrong value, the value might be clamped somewhat or a runtime-assertion should trigger
2. Compiletime: if D is initialized with the wrong value, the compilation should fail.

I can't find a solution for that.

The code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

inline void constant_assert() {}

struct C {
    constexpr C() {
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            constant_assert();
        }
    }
};

struct D {
    constexpr D(const char v) {
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            //static_assert(v < 10); // not callable
            if (v >= 10) {
                constant_assert();
            }
        }
        else {
            assert(v < 10);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    C t0; // does not trigger the check
//    constexpr C t1; // triggers the check: ok

    D d{42}; // runtime assert, but should be compiletime error!
}
```

The above code in CE: https://godbolt.org/z/16GTx797q

Comment: Are you open to exceptions? The diagnostic is as [confusing](https://godbolt.org/z/jrM9qbd6M) as the one produced by the code in the already posted answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  D d{42}; // runtime assert, but should be compiletime error!
> ```

In the way you want it, it is not possible. Your method is fine - if your arguments are to be constant evaluated, do `constexpr D d{42}`. See explanation of `is_constant_evaulated` - I found https://gist.github.com/Som1Lse/5309b114accc086d24b842fd803ba9d2.

---

You can use the gcc extension `__builtin_constant_p` calling a function with an error attribute (and optimizations maybe are needed to be enabled). This method is typically used in C by library implementations - see `_FORTIFY_LEVEL` in `glibc`.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

__attribute__((__error__("Och nooo")))
void undefined_function();

struct D {
    constexpr D(const int v) {
        if (__builtin_constant_p(v)) {
            if (v >= 10)
                undefined_function();
        } else {
            assert(v < 10);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    D d1{42};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply do this:

```
struct D {
  constexpr D(const char v) {
    assert(v < 10);
  }
};
```

- If `D` is assigned the wrong value at run time, it will trigger `assert` at **run time**.
- If `D` is assigned the wrong value at compile-time, then it will occur a **compile-time error** since `assert` is not satisfied.

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/z57858qqG)

Comment: That is not a solution to the above problem: your code is a simplified version of the above example. I want the last line in main() to fail at compile-time.

Comment: @wimalopaan. How is that possible? What you do is to check the run-time value at compile time.